# how to create multiple property decorators in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I create multiple property decorators with self defined function as getter and setter based on following class structure? I have try to use
`setattr(self, 'a', property(_to_get('a'), _to_set('a')))` but it does not work.

```py
class ABC:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def _to_get(self, attr):
        return something_function(attr)

    def _to_set(self, attr, value):
        dosomething_function(attr, value)

    @property
    def a(self):
        res = self._to_get('a')
        return res.split(' ')[0]

    @a.setter
    def a(self, value)
        self._to_set('a', value)

    @property
    def b(self):
        res = self._to_get('b')
        return res.split(' ')[1]

    @b.setter
    def b(self, value)
        self._to_set('b', value)

    @property
    def c(self):
        res = self._to_get('c')
        return res.split(' ')[2]

    @c.setter
    def c(self, value)
        self._to_set('c', value)
```

Answer (score 0):

No reason why something like this wouldn't work:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._a = None

    @property
    def a(self):
        return self._a

    @a.setter
    def a(self, x):
        self._a = x

    @a.deleter
    def a(self):
        del self._a

    @property
    def b(self):
        return self._b

    @b.setter
    def b(self, x):
        self._b = x

    @b.deleter
    def b(self):
        del self._b

    @property
    def c(self):
        return self._c

    @c.setter
    def c(self, x):
        self._c = x

    @c.deleter
    def c(self):
        del self._c
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider your original class written without decorator syntax. (The translation may not be 100% accurate, but should be close enough to illustrate the point I want to make.)

```
class ABC:
    def _to_get(self, attr):
        return something_function(attr)

    def _to_set(self, attr, value):
        dosomething_function(attr, value)

    a = property(lambda self: ABC._to_get(self, 'a').split(' ')[0],
                 lambda self, value: ABC._to_set(self, 'a', value))
    b = property(lambda self: ABC._to_get(self, 'b').split(' ')[1],
                 lambda self, value: ABC._to_set(self, 'b', value))
    c = property(lambda self: ABC._to_get(self, 'c').split(' ')[2],
                 lambda self, value: ABC._to_set(self, 'c', value))
```

`a`, `b` and `c` are all *basically* the same thing, but parameterized
by the name of the property and an integer.

```
def make_getter(attr, x):
    def getter(self):
        return self._to_get(attr).split(' ')[x]
    return getter

def make_setter(attr):
    def setter(self, value):
        self._to_set(attr, value)
    return setter

class ABC:
    def _to_get(self, attr):
        return something_function(attr)

    def _to_set(self, attr, value):
        dosomething_function(attr, value)

    a = property(make_getter('a', 0), make_setter('a'))
    b = property(make_getter('b', 1), make_setter('b'))
    c = property(make_getter('c', 2), make_setter('c'))
```

---

Something like the following should also work (not heavily tested), moving the logic into a subclass of `property`.

```
class Foo(property):
    def __init__(self, x):
        super().__init__(self._to_get, self._to_set)
        self.x = x

    # name is the class attribute the instance of Foo
    # will be assigned to
    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        self.attr = name

    # In both of the following, obj is the instance that actually
    # invokes the parameter. You would probably want to pass it
    # to something_function and do_something as well.
    def _to_get(self, obj):
        return something_function(self.attr).split(' ')[self.x]

    def _to_set(self, obj, value):
        do_something(self.attr, value)


class ABC:
    a = Foo(0)  # Will call a.__set_name__(ABC, 'a')
    b = Foo(1)  # Will call b.__set_name__(ABC, 'b')
    c = Foo(2)  # Will call c.__set_name__(ABC, 'c')
```

Comment: What version of Python are you using? `__set_name__` is new in Python 3.6. For earlier versions, a workaround would be to pass the name explicitly to `__init__`, and set `self.attr` there along with `self.x`: `a = Foo(0, 'a')`.

Comment: I have python 3.7.3

Comment: Hm. Not sure what the problem is. I'm going to add an intermediate solution based more closely on the decorator-free version of your original; maybe that will work better for you.